# How to install Connectors in Squeak 4.5

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I would like to install the latest Connectors from the ss3 repository here http://ss3.gemstone.com/ss/Connectors.html

I'm having difficulty installing in Squeak 4.5. Using the Installer script results in MessageNotUnderstood: InstallerUrl>>project:

This is the Installer script

```
(Installer url: 'http://ss3.gemstone.com/ss/')
    project: 'Connectors';
    install: 'BroomMorphs-Base';
    install: 'BroomMorphs-Connectors';
    install: 'CGPrereqs';
    install: 'Connectors';
    install: 'ConnectorsBasicDistro';
    install: 'ConnectorsDemo';
    install: 'ConnectorsGraphLayout';
    install: 'ConnectorsShapes';
    install: 'ConnectorsText';
    install: 'ConnectorsTools';
    install: 'FSM'
```

How do I do this?

Comment: The problem at hand is a pending bug in SqueakSource as used on ss3.gemtalksystems.com. the `url:` part actually should be `repository:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The install order is wrong, you can use:

```
(Installer repository: 'http://ss3.gemstone.com/ss/') 
    project: 'Connectors';
    install: 'FSM';
    install: 'BroomMorphs-Base';
    install: 'BroomMorphs-Connectors';
    install: 'CGPrereqs';
    install: 'Connectors';
    install: 'ConnectorsText';
    install: 'ConnectorsTools';
    install: 'ConnectorsShapes';
    install: 'ConnectorsBasicDistro';
    install: 'ConnectorsDemo';
    install: 'ConnectorsGraphLayout'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to install into Squeak4.5-13680with the following slight order change, was getting an error about missing NCPartsBin with the previous recommended order:

```
install: 'ConnectorsShapes';
install: 'ConnectorsTools';
```

After the load, use the World/flaps... menu to show Shared tabs.